# Is there any elegant way to push an object into front of python tuple?

Tags: python

I'm using django's [*debug_toolbar*](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) and I need to insert it's name of middleware class before other default middlewares in *tuple* `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` of `settings.py` because it's order affects behavior of the *debug_toolbar*.

---

So what I want is something like

`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.push_front('debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')`

rather than doing

`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ('debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',) + MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

where `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` is a *tuple*.

Is there any better way to avoid writing the original tuple twice?

Comment: What is debug_toolbar?

Comment: @Tichodroma I updated my question and made a link to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuples are immutable, so you can't do anything like `mytuple.append(value)`. You will always need to create a new one (or change the type of it to list, then insert the value and change it back) in order to change the value in the variable. If your code does not require using tuples, it's much easier to use lists for this.

Comment: accepted your answer for pointing out that python tuples are immutable

Answer (score 2):

If you don't absolutely need a tuple, but are ok with a list, you could use

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [... whatever]
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.insert(0, 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')
```

Semantically lists are for things like, well, lists, i. e. enumerations of things which are of the same (or a similiar) nature. Tuples are used for combining things, what often can happen with elements of a list.

`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` sounds like if you'd want to list some classes to be used in the middleware, so even semantically, a list would be better.

Comment: "enumerations of things which are of the same (or a similiar) nature" Really? I've never heard that before! Do you know if there's optimisations in Python to support that?

Comment: @TotempaaltJ: no there's no "optimisation" or whatever here, it's just  semantic.

Comment: @TotempaaltJ: It's just a semantic thing to use lists for homogeneous collections and to use tuples for heterogeneous collections, so the position of an item in a tuple _may_ be of significance, but the position of an item in a list probably shouldn't be (so you can sort a list if you like without destroying information). But (IMHO) the mutable / immutable distinction is more important. OTOH, there are namedtuples when you _really_ want to make the heterogeneity explicit.

Comment: @TotempaaltJ No, there are indeed no such optimizations I'd be aware of. And as a beginner, I used to use tuples for (nearly) everything that was immutable. But that's not the right approach...

Comment: @glglgl: My rule of thumb: Use a tuple unless you need mutability. But don't use a list if the position of an item in the collection has significance, even if you _think_ you need mutability. So something like `(latitude, longitude, altitude)` ought to be a tuple, not a list.